# How to Refactor this code to not nest more than 3 "if"

Tags: python

This function in python downloads a file to AWS S3 bucket. I have a problem with the code that I want to not nest the three "If" so that the code can be more clear and readable :

```
            for fileinfo in response['Contents']:
                if key in fileinfo['Key']:
                    if '/' in fileinfo['Key']:
                        filekeysplit = fileinfo['Key'].rsplit('/', 1)
                        if filekeysplit[1] == '':
                            continue
                        if not os.path.exists(file):
                            os.makedirs(file)
                        fileout = os.path.join(file, filekeysplit[1])
                        self._s3.download_file(bucket, fileinfo['Key'], fileout)
                    else:
                        self._s3.download_file(bucket, fileinfo['Key'], file)
```

How to do that ? thank you

Comment: 1) the duplicated `self._s3.download_file` should be fixed as well... 2) logging should be built on top of working functionality... don't mix it.

Comment: So a key that ends in `/` is invalid and should be skipped too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always invert a test and use `continue` to skip the iteration:

```
for fileinfo in response['Contents']:
    if key not in fileinfo['Key']:
        continue
    if '/' not in fileinfo['Key']:
        self._s3.download_file(bucket, fileinfo['Key'], file)
        continue

    filekeysplit = fileinfo['Key'].rsplit('/', 1)
    if filekeysplit[1] == '':
        continue
    if not os.path.exists(file):
        os.makedirs(file)
    fileout = os.path.join(file, filekeysplit[1])
    self._s3.download_file(bucket, fileinfo['Key'], fileout)
```

We can pull out the double `download_file()` call; skip keys that end in `/` *early*. You only need to create directories *once*, outside the loop (I'd rename `file` to `directory` here too). I'd use `str.rpartition()` here instead of `str.rsplit()`:

```
# file has been renamed to directory, no need to test,
# as `os.makedirs()` does this for us
os.makedirs(directory)

for fileinfo in response['Contents']:
    if key not in fileinfo['Key']:
        continue
    __, slash, basename = fileinfo['Key'].rpartition('/')
    if not basename and slash:  # ended in "/"
        continue

    target = directory
    if slash:  # there was a partition
        target = os.path.join(target, basename)
    self._s3.download_file(bucket, fileinfo['Key'], target)
```

Comment: There is a problem , you forgot to calculate the value of ` filekeysplit` before the condition `if filekeysplit[1] == '':`

Comment: @Cloudgls: thanks, I was rewriting some more and forgot to put that back in. Another update is coming.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest using some features of the standard library. Like Martijn Pieters said, you should have renamed your `file` variable to `target_directory` or something like that because it could confuse the reader of you code if you don't:

```
for fileinfo in response['Contents']:
    filepath_retrieved = fileinfo['Key']
    if key in filepath_retrieved:
        pathname_retrieved, filename_retrieved = os.path.split(filepath_retrieved)
        if pathname_retrieved:
            if filename_retrieved:
                os.makedirs(target_directory, exist_ok=True)
                output_filepath = os.path.join(target_directory, filename_retrieved)
                self._s3.download_file(bucket, filepath_retrieved, output_filepath)
        else:
            output_filepath = target_directory
            self._s3.download_file(bucket, filepath_retrieved, output_filepath)
```

The features used are:

- [`os.path.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.split) instead of str.rsplit() or str.rpartition() because it looks like you wanted to retrieve a filename at the end of a filepath when you tried to do `fileinfo['Key'].rsplit('/', 1)`
- `exist_ok` argument of [`os.makedirs()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs) so you don't have to worry about the existence of directory before you need to create it.